# create generic type from generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to declare a generic type based on another generic type without success.

The objective is the write my own test framework and to type some parameters depending on another one (the method).

```js
type Arguments<T> = T extends (...args: infer U) => any ? U : never;

// my custom test method
const methodCall = <T extends (...args: any) => any>(args: {
  method: T;
  response: ReturnType<T>;
  myArguments: Arguments<T>;
}): boolean => {
  const { method, myArguments, response } = args;
  return method.apply(null, myArguments) === response;
};

const test1 = (toto: string) => {
  return toto === "success";
};

// usage of my custom function
methodCall({
  method: test1,
  myArguments: ["fail"],
  response: false
});


// this is what I want to type
interface MyHelpers {
  methodCall: any // HOW TO TYPE THIS? 
  methodCall2: (args: { flag: boolean }) => boolean;
}

// I would expose only the helpers object
const helpers = (): MyHelpers = {
  methodCall: <T extends (...args: any) => any>(args: {
    method: T;
    response: ReturnType<T>;
    myArguments: Arguments<T>;
  }): boolean => {
    const { method, myArguments, response } = args;
    return method.apply(null, myArguments) === response;
  },
  methodCall2: (args: { flag: boolean }): boolean => {
    return args.flag;
  }
};
```

I'm expecting another object calling helpers to be able with `helpers().methodCall(...)` to be typed as it is declared in helpers. Not with `any`.

The playground can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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).

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close, if I understand you correctly. You can choose between function syntax (where you define the signature of `methodCall` as if you're defining a function implementation) and property syntax (where you define `methodCall` as a property that happens to be a lambda, which is close to how you have it).

If you use the function syntax, you define the generic in angle brackets (`<>`), the parameter list between parentheses, and **the return type after a colon**; it's as if you're defining a function without a body. If you use the property syntax, you're defining a lambda, with the generic in angle brackets, the parameter list between parentheses, and **the return type after a fat arrow (`=>`)**; you're defining a property by that name and putting your type—[a function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#writing-the-function-type)—after the colon. Either way will work for you.

(I've also switched from your custom `Arguments` utility type to [the undocumented `Parameters` built-in](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.3/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1456-L1464).)

```js
interface MyHelpers {
  methodCall<T extends (...args: any) => any>(args: {
    method: T;
    response: ReturnType<T>;
    myArguments: Parameters<T>;
  }): boolean;
  methodCall2: (args: { flag: boolean }) => boolean;
}

interface MyHelpersWithObjectSyntax {
  methodCall: <T extends (...args: any) => any>(args: {
    method: T;
    response: ReturnType<T>;
    myArguments: Parameters<T>;
  }) => boolean;
  methodCall2: (args: { flag: boolean }) => boolean;
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0CMMC8MAUUTYFw2gCcBLMAcwEo0A+GAbwCgYZD4oBXQsOHENVdACII7YMEQRBAbgYBfGQ1IJCAMwCG4mAFkAngAl4AGwAO8QhHpMYAWzYALEABMAwmsOGAPABUY8AB4IYI4WGAB04WqEZBD4amA6VKi0cTrUGJHR+IzMzLZQDo74XjI5LIjG4BDw+ABKbJxgXjqm3tQlOdY6AIJR7LZgUDEwAAqRanlmEK3tshT4AEYgIIbwcVLMAPQbMADuxPkwajCghuBWeQWu7gBM+OlRQ3QwKoZqZAtLK3EwszQwi8tVmAZLIGIoBmZ1JpdAYTJMAOr7OzDQggUyEKA6ADKOgGaj8lly9icV0M+G8vgC8CCIXCoQyQxSiWS8TSDKyViJ+ScRXazFYEAqkGqMDqHC4TRaXjanJs3V6-UG+FGhHGbEm0ysvyS-0+QPWMC2uyRh2ealgkVRO3OxJcbkMt0w7Poz1e711gO+2toAK+wLkYNAkFgdiM6KGGAwzO0+jDk0SmGjGGyNltpPJPn8gWCmDpzqZfxSbIeHNKFx5MGKsoFQqqtXqEua8E1ZflZD61KVIzGE3MLZ+cw9fr+KeYQegLvLjgANHKeu3FRBZzXKvAfmhDg8+WVxdwp-TjMZDDoMGB2O5Z515x2BhBEgIyoLVzNpzbuXabndnU8Xm8Pp7uFmf9hx1UcdwaTdolCX8yBmOQKAUUM4XMKNQinUlkzfAp8AQZBX1yNsby7ABtQR1GIQxBAAXXwx9axFdRDCqeCpCAA)